# Programmatic connection validity check for a Postgresql database in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, database-connection

I have a stand-alone java application that makes some database read/write business on a postgresql database. I used the isValid function available on a java.sql.Connection object in order to re-establish the database connection in case it is lost/fails possibly due to a network problem/crash. The following code snippet shows this idea shortly:

```
  //dbConnection is an instance of java.sql.Connection

  if(dbConnection.isValid(1)){
     reEstablishConnection();
  }
```

Nevertheless, at run-time I am getting an exception within the condition of above if block, which says that the method 'isValid' is not implemented yet. I am using the latest JDBC driver (v9.1-101) and my postgesql DBMS version is 8.3.9. I installed it using Yast2 on a SUSe Linux (SLES 11 SP2 - 64 bit). Can someone tell me me how I can check if the connection is lost programmatically in Java for postgresql? My inention is to reconnect automatically without the user intervention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement your own connection validity check function (something like executing `"select 1"` and returning true if 1 is returned from db without error).

However, I suggest you to use [connection pooling](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/conpool.html) and I recommend to use the the [Apache Tomcat Pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html), that will handle for you validity checking on connections (among many other things)